# How to get invoice ID of settled Executions

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Lets say i have table with the Name Executions like this :

```
InvoiceID------ExecutionID-------IsSettled

123-----1-----0

123-----2-----1

345-----3-----1

345-----4-----1

567-----5-----0

567-----6-----0
```

**My Question :**

What is the query  that retrieves only InvoiceIDs where all it's Executions have IsSettled=1.?
I mean the result of the query should be like this:

```
345-----3-----1

345-----4-----1
```

i want to execulde any invoices that has any executions with isSettled flog=0,in my question u will find tha invocieID=123 has 2 executions ,one with IsSettled flag=0 and another Execution with Issettled flag=1, so i dont want to include this invoice in my result set as it has one execution with isSettled flag =0

If anyone knows also if I have an Execution Object how can i get the same result using Linq.

The query can be either SQL or LINQ

Thanks

Comment: It's always worth checking MSDN for things like this. See here for basic Linq usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397927.aspx

Comment: i know linq ,but this is not straight forward as u think plz read my question again ,andu will notice that i dont want to retrive any invoice where isSettled flag=1 ,,i want only invoices where all its executions isSettled flag =1...,

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of invoices Id's that are not settled:

```
var notNeeded = ExecutionObject.Where(e => e.IsSettled == 0).Select(s => s.InvoiceId).ToList();
```

Then filter on the invoices that are settled and ensure the invoice id is in the not settled list.

```
var invoices = ExecutionObject.Where(e => e.IsSettled == 1 && !notNeeded.Contains(e.InvoiceId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Darren,,but this is not whati want only invoices where all it's executions IsSettled flag=1 ,,ifu notice that InvoiceID is not the primary key,lock @ InvoiceID Column u will notice that invoiceID can be duplicated according to number of executions

Comment: @user2120457 - this will filter and give you all invoices where `IsSettled flag = 1`

Comment: ur linq query will also include invoiceID=123,and thats is wrong according to my logic as it has one execution with IsSettled Flag=0

Comment: @user2120457 Invoice ID: 123 has `IsSettled = 1` in your question... `"123-----2-----1"`

Comment: @user2120457 - have you actually ran the query? How can it bring back any results with IsSettled = 0?  In the query you've explicitly stated that you want `IsSettled == 1` which is all it can bring back.

Comment: Dears, i want to execulde any invoices that has any executions with isSettled flog=0,in my question u will find tha invocieID=123 has 2 executions ,one with IsSettled flag=0 and another Execution with Issettled flag=1, so i dont want to include this invoice in my result set as it has one execution with isSettled flag =0

Comment: @user2120457 - I've adjusted my answer

Comment: This answer is not pretty, the use of ToList() prevents the query from being optimized in the database.  With a lot of records this involves a lot of data back and forth.

Comment: @BobVale - how does it prevent the query from being optimized? I'm simply resolving it rather than using deferred execution.

Comment: Because by using ToList() it means that your subset is pulled back to the client and then passed out again to the server on the next query.  You really want the subquery to execute all on the serverside

Comment: @DarrenDavies for example with this example if there are 10000 invoice_id's  that match the first query, the client will retrieve 10000 ids and then the next query will post those 10000 id's back again, over a slow link this is suboptimal, additionally there is a limit to how many values in a list you can pass back.

Comment: @BobVale - I'd like to see some statistics.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Additionally there is a limit of 2100 parameters on a request, so with the 10000 invoice_id's this query will throw an exception.

Comment: @BobVale - please provide some documentation about this and some actual statistics rather than stating it will do this and that. First my query wasn't optimized and now it will throw an exception? Yet your query is correct even though it has a score of -3?

Comment: @DarrenDavies I have no idea why I have -3, nobody has bothered to explain their mark downs.  However please see the Microsoft documentation for limits on parameters (MSDN)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx] and also do a google search for the error "Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. the maximum is 2100" to see examples of this problem.

Comment: @DarrentDavies, I'd have to create some dummy data to produce statistics but can you not see that this query requires a round trip to the server requesting all the id's and then sending them back to the server again.  Scale up, what if there are million records or 10 million, this will use memory on your client, whereas SQL server can choose to use temporary tables etc.

Comment: @BobVale - just looked at that link. I'm not specifying more than 2,100 parameters to a stored procedure or a function........What are you talking about?

Comment: @DarrenDavies when you pass a LOCAL collection to a LINQ query every value within that collection is passed as an individual parameter, so a 10000 strong collection sends 10000 parameters

Comment: @BobVale - the user has already retrieved the data from the database and stored it in `ExecutionObject` ... I'm simply filtering on that list.  Behind the scenes if the collection needs to go back to the database it will simply use the parameter I stated (`IsSettled`) - it will not include > 2,100 parameters.

Comment: @DarrenDavies so your solution retrieves every object from the database and then queries it how is that optimal? If Execution object is a linq deferred query object the parameters will be include due to the nature of your query passing them in the where clause.#

Comment: @BobVale - OP already stated they have the `ExecutionObject` .. I didn't create this for them. Also I pass one parameter back ('IsSettled') not 2,1000 parameters as you were stating I was.

Comment: @DarrenDavies You pass back the collection `notneeded`.  This is a localcollection that could potential end up with more than 2100 entries.  When talking linq in a database context it reasonable to assume that execution object would be an IQuerable for deferred execution against the database.

Answer (score 1):

***The query can be either SQL or LINQ***

**`Query`**

```
select * from Executions 
where InvoiceID in 
(
select InvoiceID from Executions 
group by InvoiceID
having min(Issettled)=1
)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d60b0/1)**

Comment: it is not working i get this error as IsSettled is bit.
Operand data type bit is invalid for min operator.

Comment: i solved it  by cast IsSettled to int but can u plz tell me what is the effect of this workaround on performance or is there any better solution.
select * from Executions 
where InvoiceID in 
(
select InvoiceID from Executions 
group by InvoiceID
having min(cast( Issettled as int))=1
)

Comment: @user2120457, I have no idea why I'm marked down, but the ANY and the ALL sql clauses are designed to be the optimal way for this sort of query

Comment: Thanks Bob Vale,,i am trying ur query and i will get back to u.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a linq query (you haven't told us) then you could use: -

```
var settled = executions.GroupBy(id => id.invoiceid).Where(inv => inv.All(s => s.issettled)).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: yes it will get all invoices where isSettled=0 ,and i dont want that i want only invoices where all it's executions IsSettled flag=1 ,,ifu notice that InvoiceID is not the primary key,lock @ InvoiceID Column u will notice that invoiceID can be duplicated according to number of executions

Comment: ? `IsSettled = 1` in this query. Also, is this query in Linq or SQL? You didn't specify

Comment: in both SQL query or Linq Query

Comment: OH okay, you really need to be more clear. In that case you could group by the invoice id

Comment: i edited my question,,thank u DGIBBS ,,i will try it and get back to u

Comment: @BobVale Yeah, it is _now_

Comment: @DGibbs much better!  also why not just `Select(x => x.Key)` to get the unique invoice_id's instead of getting all the invoices - question asks for the ids.

Answer (score 0):

<del>It'd be something as simple as the following in linq:

Executions.Where(e => e.IsSettled == 1)</del>

After understanding the question and giving it a go in LinqPad the following Linq query will get what you need:

```
Executions.GroupBy(e => e.InvoiceId)
          .Where(g => g.All(e => e.IsSettled == true))
          .SelectMany(g => g)
```

The linq script is avaliable here: http://share.linqpad.net/fawl6l.linq

Comment: yes it will get all invoices where isSettled=1 ,and i dont want that i want only invoices where all it's executions IsSettled flag=1 ,,ifu notice that InvoiceID is not the primary key,lock @ InvoiceID Column u will notice that invoiceID can be duplicated according to number of executions

Comment: @user2120457 Ah I understand now, the question isn't too clear on the matter. As mentioned in another answer, you'll want to group by InvoiceID.

Comment: as e.IsSettled is boolean you could just skip the `== true` ie `g.All(e => e.IsSettled)` aslo instead of selectmany just use `Select(g => g.Key)` to get unique list of invoice_ids

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
var invoices = (from execution in ExecutionObject
            where execution.IsSettled == 1
            && !ExecutionObject.Where(x=>x.IsSettled == 0).Select(y=>y.InvoiceID).Contains(execution.InvoiceID)
            select execution.InvoiceID).Distinct().ToList();
```

I haven't tested it, but the idea is that you filter first by IsSettled == 1 and then remove any that have a record where IsSettled == 0.

Comment: Wouldn't an `Any` clause be better here, I'm not sure how well the SQL translation would optimize this.

Answer (score -4):

I think the key point here is you want invoices where there is not a settled = 0?

```
select distinct InvoiceID 
from executions
where invoiceID <> ALL(select invoice_id from executions where is_settled = 0)
```

or in linq

```
var q = from i in ctx.Invoices
        where ctx.Invoices.All(x => is_settled == 1 || x.invoice_id != i.invoice_id)
        select i.invoice_id;

var result = q.Distinct();
```

Comment: Why do I have so many votes down.  What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Come on people, don't vote me down for the shear hell of it, please justify why I am marked down and what is wrong with my answer.